# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in aspx

Tags: asp.net

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

i inherit the BasePage class like below:

public partial class monthly_statement : BasePage

```
lbldate.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8).ToString("MMM yyyy");

lbldaterange.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(lbldate.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + Convert.ToDateTime(lbldate.Text).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Convert.ToDateTime. The documentation says that the current culture is used when parsing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx

=> that can throw error because your current culture can not parse from utc

so, you can try DateTime.Parse or DateTime.ParseExact methods